# Is there a file manager with Mac Os like column view for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

[image]
Is there a file manager that supports navigating the folders and sub folders in the same window as finder does in OSX?

Comment: One of the cool things about Gnu/Linux is that the graphical-user-interface is not the operating system. There for you can change it independently to the operating system. You can also change the file browser. I did a search on `linux file browser` and found a few that look promising `midnight commander (mc)`, `krusader`. There may be more.

Comment: @richard thanks for the quick response and idea .........

Comment: @richard i heard about the `mirlin` but it is not working in the `ubntu 16.04` it is for `14.04`

Comment: Often when we change from one system to another, we compare the new with the old, but never the old with the new (because we do not know yet what the new can do), sometimes we never learn what the new can do.

Comment: @richard you gotta nice point .......  which file system you will suggest if you have to suggest one means ?

Comment: A file-system is another thing that you can change in Gnu/Linux, but we are writing about a file-browser. I use dolphin: because I use the command line a LOT, and it has an integrated command-line-terminal, the new one is so integrated that I can change directory in command-line, or Gui and it is reflected in the other. You may like something else. Decide what your values are (e.g. command-line vs gui, low-resource vs glitter vs ease of use, high information vs simple).

Answer (score 30):

Yes. It's Elementary OS's Pantheon File manager. Install it using this ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

[image: pantheon file managers multi pane]

Activate this option by clicking the third button on the left hand side of the location bar.

Comment: it doesn't really work in Ubuntu 16.04, sometimes crashes or gets stuck sometimes. I also notice that my python scripts were writting slower, if Pantheon was displaying the directories that I was writting on. The icons also appear a bit crooked. I tried to get used to it and tweak it a bit, but I gave up after a coule of days. Nevertheless, it seems to be the only file manager that **currently** supports [Miller's columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_columns), and that is not console base (see [Ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/wiki/Official-user-guide))

Comment: yum / dnf install pantheon-files for redhat/centos/fedora thing

Answer (score 1):

I got the following working on ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

If the install fails, try manual installation of dependencies from [here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libcloudproviders0_0.3.0-1_amd64.deb.html)

References:

[1] [How to install Pantheon Files on Ubuntu and Linux Mint](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/install-pantheon-file-manager-ubuntu.html)